# Any 16-bit TMS/WMS tile renderer/servers?

Tags: geoserver, tiles, software-recommendations, mapnik, gdal2tiles

I am looking for something like Geoserver or gdal2tiles.py that can render tiles to 16 bit PNG files (grey-scale).  The tech needs to be open source.  The geoserver PNG grey-scale output is not 16 bit but an 8-bit two band image which is no good for my use-case (I need a single-band 16-bit image). gdal2tiles also produces 8-bits.  I thought of using Mapnik as a renderer and then tilestache or some combination like that, but Mapnik offers only 8 or 32 bit PNGs and no 16 bits according to the [documentation](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/OutputFormats).

I want to tile according to a well-known grid and have 16-bit single-band tiles served over well-known web protocols (tms, wms).  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Although my inputs are also 16-bit they do not conform to a suitable tiling scheme and are in EPSG 4326 when I want them in 3857, so I have to retile and reproject and can't just use the original files.  So I am looking for the convenience of a renderer that will produce 16-bit tiles conforming to tms or wms, with caching

Comment: 16-bit raster input, or are you creating this from some vector source?

Comment: The inputs are also 16-bit rasters (for now), but the important thing is 16-bit output.

Comment: Tile servers are typically made for on-screen usage and they serve 8-bytes-per-band tiles either as png or jpeg. Gdal2tiles is a python script https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py and it might not be too hard to edit it to support a new outputformat for tiles. For MapServer it is rather easy to configure 16-bit TIFF outputformat and with not-so-often used tile mode http://www.mapserver.org/output/tile_mode.html you might get something usable.